# Laravel 5.4 Validation Using Form Requests

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to use Form Requests to validate Model so i started by create `php artisan make:request TaskRequest` and after i add in TaskRequest class `

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|min:5',
        ];
    }   
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'name.required' => 'A title is required',
        ];
    }
`
```

and in My logic

```
Route::post('/tasks',function (\App\Http\Requests\TaskRequest $request){

    $task = new \App\Task();
    $task->name = $request->input("name");
    $task->save();

    return response()->json(['task was created',$task], http_response_code());
});
```

So when i try to add a task i get error `HttpException, This action is unauthorized.,AuthorizationException ...`

It was work for me without Validation. So how can i fix this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every (self-created) request has an `authorize` function that determines if the user is allowed to send the request. This can be useful to check for admin privileges or similar.

In you case, you can simply return `true`. More information can be found in the [corresponding docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#authorizing-form-requests)

Your authorize function in your `TaskRequest` would look like this:

```
/**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: thanks @manniL how can i get message from when not created (task), now i get page HTML for index page of laravel ?

Comment: You are welcome! For displaying validation errors please refer to [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors)

Comment: Ok @manniL but i want to get errors in json when validation has errors, there is a way to do this.

Comment: Sure, you can do that! But you should find information on how to do that easily :)

Answer (score 0):

In your custom request class for "form request" which contains the validation logic pass `return:true;` instead of `return:false;` and then it will work like a charm.

The code will look like something as following,

```
    namespace App\Http\Requests;

    use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

    class portfolioValidate extends FormRequest
    {
        /**
         * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
         *
         * @return bool
         */
        public function authorize()
        {
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public function rules()
        {
            return [
                'title'=> 'required',
                'content'=> 'required'
            ];
        }
    }
```

as you can use middleware to make authentication for the page which contains this form... so we don't need that authorization in the `FormRequest` class. So returning true will make it(validation) authorized for all cases.

I think now it is clear to everyone now.